Do HQL / JPA ORM needs 100% compliance with relational DB Table details of a DB or is it not needed to work in HQL / JPQL
Do HQL / JPA ORM relies on compliance 100% with the DB Table details like all columns and foreign key relational details are captured in the JPA ORM. Since in my past, I was able to query a Oracle Table where in DB Team has updated few of the Column details in Oracle DB Table which was not updated in the Hibernate ORM, but yet the HQL Query / Oracle ORM Objects did not make any noise or issues, but rather functioning without any errors or issues.
Do we need to have 100% compliance with the relational or current state available in Hibernate ORM / JPA Entity Bean for it to interact with DB Layer without any issues or if is it not the case as still the outdated ORM works with updated DB Table, Kindly share your inputs with pointers to such materials on the net.
